# How to find the exact element path without using xpath

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I'm currently trying to locate this check box. I know I can use a xpath to locate it but I'm trying to see if there's a more efficient way of doing it. The problem I'm seeing is that there are multiple div class with the same name. I'm trying to find this specific one and isolate it. I'm trying to make my code more efficient if possible.

Xpath

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/cow-data/cat-panel/section/div[1]/div/div/md-        checkbox[4]/div[1]
```

Element path:

```
<div class="cd-container" cd-gar-ripple="" cd-gar-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="cd-icon"></div></div>
```

Code I'm trying to use:

```
find('cd-container').click
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the div id 'cd-container' has multiple occurrences on the page and thus this doesn't work. I'm trying to see if I can find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed explanation of the problem? Without knowing what the HTML actually looks like, it's impossible for us to know whether a proposed solution might actually work; and nor can I really give an opinion whether it's the "best" approach.

Comment: Maybe you need to fetch the 4th occurrence? Or the only occurrence within another class? Or the sibling to another element? Or filter by another property too? ..... I really cannot say, without a more "realistic" example!

Comment: Hey Tom,
So I'm trying to write code where I'm trying to look for this particular checkbox. I can always get a full xpath and use that in my code. The problem that I'm trying to solve is if I can find a more efficient way of getting to this checkbox without using xpath. In my code, I found a div class 'cd-container'. This div class occurs multiple times in the html code so it's not a proper way to use it. It doesn't work for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I understand the question, but we cannot give an answer without a more concrete example. By what criteria might you be able to locate the element? As I said above, perhaps we could use a sibling, or `nth` element, or additional targeting, ... But I cannot say with any confidence whether which, if any, of these solutions will work without knowing a bit more about the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML ***cd-container*** is the value of the *class* attribute but not *id* attribute. So your effective line of code will be:

```
find('.cd-container').click
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an element (AND THEN), return it's xpath. Use capybara.

This will allow you to locate using text / css selector. And then you can just return the path of the element.

i.e.

```
page.find('td', text: 'Column 1').path # Random td with text
page.find('#main').path # ID
page.all('div').select { |element| element.text == 'COoL dIv' }.first.path # First div that matches certain text
page.find('.form > div:nth-of-type(2)').path # Specific structured div
page.all('p div li:nth-child(3)').sample.path # Random li
```